# How to surround xarg's inputs with more arguments?

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I'm trying to somehow use `xargs` so a program whose outputs are the lines

```
<ARG1>
<ARG2>
 ...
<ARGN>
```

will cause the execution of the following command:

```
command
    <GLOBAL_PREFIX_1> \
    <GLOBAL_PREFIX_2> \
    ...               \
    <PREFIX1> <PREFIX2> ... ARG1 <SUFFIX1> <SUFFIX2> ... \
    <PREFIX1> <PREFIX2> ... ARG2 <SUFFIX1> <SUFFIX2> ... \
                            ...                          \
    <PREFIX1> <PREFIX2> ... ARGN <SUFFIX1> <SUFFIX2> ... \
    <GLOBAL_SUFFIX_1> \
    <GLOBAL_SUFFIX_2> \
    ...
```

where the prefixes and suffixes are known beforehand, but arbitrary.

Some (probably) obvious notes that I feel like I have to explicitly state anyway:

- The parameters are **not** "nice". They lack newlines but might contain spaces, `$`, `(`, `)`, `"`, etc.
- I would like to avoid converting them to a single giant string and back if at all possible.
- Yes, I meant what I wrote. I **really** just only want **1** command to run: not 0, not 2, not 3, not `N`...
- More generally: I *don't want to spawn a new process* for each argument.
- Simpler tools are preferred, assuming correctness is given... so `xargs` is preferred over `sed`, which is preferred over `awk`, etc.
- I'm trying to use standard *nix shell tools here.
  Obviously I can write a Python script, but that's not the point...

Answer (score 1):

Forget xargs, just use a while loop. This assumes that printf is builtin

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" "command"
printf "    %s\\\n" "<GLOBAL_PREFIX_1>" "<GLOBAL_PREFIX_2>" "..."
while read -r ; do
    printf "    <PREFIX1> <PREFIX2> ... %s <SUFFIX1> <SUFFIX2> ... \\\n" "$REPLY"
done
printf "    %s\\\n" "<GLOBAL_SUFFIX_1>" "<GLOBAL_SUFFIX_2>"
printf "    %s\n" "..."
```

If the PREFIXn or SUFFIXn have `interesting` characters in them like `%` or `\` then these will need to be escaped.

Of course sed would work

```
sed '1i\
GP1\\\
GP2\\\
...\\
s/.*/P1 P2 & S1 S2\\/
$s/.*/&\
GS1\\\
GS2\\\
... '
```

For awk you have BEGIN and END clauses....

Comment: The first one spawns a new process per argument I believe, right? (Or at least it does on my system.) The `sed` one seems like it doesn't though?

Comment: Use a shell which has printf as a builtin, like bash, ksh, zsh.

Comment: Oh, actually, I assumed it wasn't a builtin because I saw `/usr/bin/printf`... but it seems it's listed under `help` (for BASH) too, never mind. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

If the arg prefix and arg postfix does not contain space, then GNU Parallel's -X is made for you:

```
seq 1000 | parallel -X echo global prefix argpre{}argpost global postfix
```

It will distribute evenly to the number of core. If you do not like that:

```
seq 1000 | parallel -j1 -n10 -X echo global prefix argpre{}argpost global postfix
```